# Error in adding a photo from my library?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, photolibrary

The code I have posted below has two functions; the first one is to take a photo (which is working fine) and the second one is for picking an image from the library (which is not working). The functions are not getting called properly. Please check my code and let me know whats wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    NSString *stringDate = nil;
    if (dateFormatter == nil) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy"];
        stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    }
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        // storing to camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
        CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(320, 436);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        xapp.profileImage=newImage;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"addImage" object:nil];
    }

    // Commit the change.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                          message: @"Failed to save image"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is the Picking from library code not working?   Does it generate an error? Does the picker come up?

Comment: The second function is called when the when the UIImagePickerController runs into an error, not when a photo was loaded from library. Can you be a bit more specific about the error? How did you invoke the UIImagePickerController for loading from library?

Comment: library is open fine If a select a image,the image is not displayed in the imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i just put code of fully capture Image From Camera of Photo library just check it out and try to impliment In your Project:-

```
-(IBAction)actionImage:(id)sender
{   
    UIActionSheet *option =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select Photo",@"Take Photo",nil];
    option.actionSheetStyle =UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [option showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (actionSheet.tag==2) 
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {

        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;

        if(buttonIndex ==0)
        {
            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
            {       
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];      
            }
        }
        else if(buttonIndex ==1)
        {
            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            {       
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];      
            }
        }   
    }
}
#pragma mark - imagePickerController Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imgUserImage.image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];    

    return;
}
```

**NOTE:-**
DO not forget Include related Framework or delegate. 
Hope its help's you no need extra coding for this stuff you just simply  do with this above method :)

Comment: library is open fine If a select a image,the image is not displayed in the imageView

Comment: check the IBOutLet is connect From Nib(XIB) or not :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes needed in your code..Here is the code for picking an image from library..I think better to give you the code rather correcting errors in yours..so, here is the code..enjoy...

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
               self,
               @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
               nil);
        }
        else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
        {
                // Code here to support video if enabled
        }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
   if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
           initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
           message: @"Failed to save image"
           delegate: nil
           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
           otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
   }
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: library is open fine If a select a image,the image is not displayed in the imageView

Comment: @IOS234   you try this code it works for me..and think works for you too...if you want any further assistance reply..